# Unable to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' for Spree API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, spree

Every time I'm trying to set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header for the Spree Commerce API, no header is being passed for Ajax calls.

I'm currently extending the base_controller.rb:

File: app/controllers/spree/api/base_controller_decorator.rb

```
after_filter :set_access_control_headers

def set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
end
```

The header is added to the requests every time I view a JSON directly from the browser. However, no header is visible when making AJAX calls...

Can anybody explain me how to do this? Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: What if you try `before_action` instead of `after_filter`? What's the version of Spree and the url requested via AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need anything in your application controller, rather you need a gem:

Add `gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'` to your Gemfile, then `bundle install`

In `config/application.rb` configure rack-cors to accept requests from any origin. It belongs anywhere inside the Application class.

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :options]
  end
end
```

`origins '*'` indicates you are allowing requests from any domain.  If you want to restrict to a specific domain (i.e. internally open an api, but keep it closed to external users), change `'*'` to the specific domain name.

see https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors for more details